# Are google plus notifications slow?

Tags: response-time, performance, google+

I'm not really a social network person but the google+'s notifications are terrible slow compared with the facebook's notifications.

When I enter to the facebook's home page notifications are the first thing in load, pretty fast indeed.

But when I enter to the google+'s home page the time for retrieve the number of notifications are too damn high. Almost 10 seconds.

[image]
[image]

**The questions are:**

- *Is this response time critical for google+?*
- *Why does a company obsessed with fast applications
  (google chrome, google os, google search, etc...) make such a
  terrible mistake?*
- *Is there something that I can use to speed up google+'s
  notifications?*

Comment: The last question isn't one we can answer here. It **might** be suitable for Web Applications, but probably won't get an answer there either.

Comment: You seem to be implying that they are intentionally making it slow.  If it is unintentional, then it is a technical issue and not something we could answer.

Comment: Google+'s bar is also loading on _almost every Google service_, meaning it's database hit is probably of lower priority than loading the current page, so I assume it's deliberately the last thing to load.

Comment: Consider asking this on Quora instead.

Comment: Back end web dev and I'm shocked by how needlessly slow it is, especially for opening notifications. They are waiting till you click on the bell before loading the notifications, when they should be preloading the contents. If the extra resources are a problem you could make it only preload when there are notifications and the number is low (I say low because this would mean the user is likely to check when they get a notification). The current situation is madness.

Answer (score 3):

Google+ is indeed quite slow. And not only on the notification. However, Google+ is still in an early stage, I believe they even still consider it to be beta software. I am sure they are working on this.

Facebook is also a company obsessed with speed. Facebook is actually an example of how a web application can be very fast, and apart from that they also do lots of stuff to make it seem fast.

Comment: Here we are, 3.5 years later, and it's *still* slow. So I'm not buying the beta argument. Let's face it, Google+ notifications are garbage at the code level and that's not going to change.